# Should I add to gitignore JPA Buddy plugin configurations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, gitignore, jpa-buddy

At IDEA Java project, I've tried to create new "Liquibase Diff Changelog" for the first time, and the JPA Buddy plugin has asked for some configurations. The plugin has created a new file with settings.
[image: part of project stucture]
Right now the file seems to just describe the general project metadata so I'd rather add it to the Git.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="DatabaseMigrationSettings">
    <database-infos>
      <database-info>
        <option name="enabled" value="true" />
        <dbms-id>postgres</dbms-id>
      </database-info>
    </database-infos>
  </component>
</project>
```

My concern is that later the plugin may store some credentials or other sensitive things to this file. Is it safe to include it into Git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to share it to Git. It's a shareable configuration for the whole team and if you want to share it with colleagues, please feel free to do so. Incase not, it can be excluded.

Also, in future, if you have similar questions, especially security wise, it's best to contact JB support directly.